# SQL select using join

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, join

I have a table called ROOM.

```
CONSTRAINT ROOM_PK PRIMARY KEY(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO),
CONSTRAINT ROOM_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES BUILDING(BUILDINGNO));


BUILDINGNO | ROOMNO | ROOMCAPACITY
-----------+--------+-------------
B1         | R1     | 121
B1         | R2     | 253
B2         | R1     | 275
B2         | R2     | 126
B2         | R3     | 124
B3         | R1     | 256    
B3         | R2     | 324
B4         | R1     | 431
B4         | R2     | 345
B4         | R3     | 231
```

And also a table called SESSION.

```
CONSTRAINT SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY(SESSIONID),
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES 
BUILDING(BUILDINGNO),
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO) REFERENCES 
ROOM(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO),
CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(SPEAKERID) REFERENCES SPEAKER(SPEAKERID)); 


SESSIONID | BUILDINGNO | ROOMNO | SPEAKERID
----------+------------+--------+----------
SS01      | B1         | R1     | S1
SS02      | B2         | R1     | S2
SS03      | B1         | R2     | S2
SS04      | B4         | R2     | S4
SS05      | B3         | R2     | S5
SS06      | B3         | R1     | S5
SS07      | B4         | R2     | S3
SS08      | B1         | R2     | S2
SS09      | B2         | R3     | S4
SS10      | B4         | R1     | S3
```

I would like to create a SELECT statement using a JOIN that displays the details of SESSION (ID, BUILDINGNO and ROOMNO) that are not in BUILDINGNO 'B2' and the ROOMCAPACITY must have > 180. Results are also to exclude duplicate values.

I tried to use the statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONFERENCESESSION.SESSIONID, CONFERENCESESSION.BUILDINGNO, CONFERENCESESSION.ROOMNO 
FROM CONFERENCESESSION 
INNER JOIN ROOM ON ROOM.ROOMNO=CONFERENCESESSION.ROOMNO 
WHERE CONFERENCESESSION.BUILDINGNO != 'B2' 
AND ROOM.ROOMCAPACITY >= '180';
```

However it is not quite right... could someone show me how to fix this please?

Comment: what is the data type of `ROOMCAPACITY ` ? and what is your problem ?

Comment: You should join table on both `BUILDINGNO` and `ROOMNO` columns.

Comment: I dont think `CONSTRAINT SESSION_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(BUILDINGNO) REFERENCES 
BUILDING(BUILDINGNO),` FK is of much use since you have `SESSION_FK2` on both `(BUILDINGNO,ROOMNO)` columns.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I shall make that change :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` the table on `BUILDINGNO` and `ROOMNO` columns. Assuming `ROOMCAPACITY` is `int`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CS.SESSIONID, 
                CS.BUILDINGNO, 
                CS.ROOMNO 
FROM 
CONFERENCESESSION CS
INNER JOIN 
ROOM R
ON R.BUILDINGNO = CS.BUILDINGNO
AND R.ROOMNO     = CS.ROOMNO 
WHERE
CS.BUILDINGNO != 'B2' 
AND R.ROOMCAPACITY >= 180;
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use the whole foreign key

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONFERENCESESSION.SESSIONID, CONFERENCESESSION.BUILDINGNO, CONFERENCESESSION.ROOMNO 
FROM CONFERENCESESSION 
INNER JOIN ROOM 
  ON ROOM.BUILDINGNO = CONFERENCESESSION.BUILDINGNO
  ON ROOM.ROOMNO     = CONFERENCESESSION.ROOMNO 
 AND CONFERENCESESSION.BUILDINGNO != 'B2' 
 AND ROOM.ROOMCAPACITY >= '180';
```